# Can't get a Gradient Texture in a rounded shape

Tags: materials, node-editor

I was following this cartoony eye tutorial https://youtu.be/qPwrzqeaZ0U?t=86 but instead of black circle i get this

[image: eyeball]

black gradient comes from left to right. My eye is unwrapped. Nodes look exactly like those from video:

[image: nodes]

This is how my UV map looks:

[image: UV map]

So where is the problem?

Comment: Didn't you remap the UV?

Comment: I added to the post how does my UV look

Comment: The iris is too small and not in the center. To make the shader work the iris must be in the center. Select only the iris on the 3D model so you see only the iris in the UV editor. Then in the UV editor, select the menu entry *UV > Pack Islands* to scale it up. Alternately, select the front view for the eyeball in the 3D viewport, and UV Unwrap with *Project from View* (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NoYF.jpg)

Comment: It works! Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

To follow this tutorial, you must <kbd>U</kbd> unwrap the iris-area *on its own*..

[image]

.. to center it in the UV texture-space. This part of the eye is being implemented as a separate material, so the mapping of any other faces doesn't matter.